# Classic ASP AESDecrypt for SagePay 3.00

Tags: asp-classic, opayo

I am using classic asp to upgrade to SagePay 3.00.

When receiving the crypt response back from SagePay, I am successfully decrypting that and displaying the long string on the screen.

What I need to do is separate the pairs so I can use that information, such as VendorTxCode.

I have successfully used rijndael.asp and includes.asp to Encrypt, send the information to SagePay and decrypt.

How can I perform what I think is the final task by listing the values separately from the string?

I have encrypted and decrypted with these two functions :

```
public function EncryptAndEncode(strIn) 
        '** AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding - DEFAULT **
        EncryptAndEncode="@" & AESEncrypt(strIn,strEncryptionPassword)

end function

** Wrapper function do decode then decrypt based on header of the encrypted field **

public function DecodeAndDecrypt(strIn)
    DecodeAndDecrypt=AESDecrypt(mid(strIn,2),strEncryptionPassword) 
end function
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, following on from the question above, I have successfully encrypted the information to send to SagePay, received it back and successfully decrypted it into a single string. The problem is, I need to grab the individual data.

Comment: Could you show an example of string decripted?

Comment: Do you have an example of the format of the decrypted string? It sounds like you just need to split the string based on some type of delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vbscript
dim decryptedString, values, value

decryptedString = "value1,value2,value3"

values = Split("decryptedString", ",")

for each value in values
    Response.Write(value & "<br />")
next
```

Depending on the delimiter a regular expression might be required.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response and help.

This is what I have now :

transinfo = Request.QueryString("Crypt")

decryptthis = DecodeAndDecrypt(transinfo)

Which successfully receives the string, the decrypts it. I am still unsure how to take the individual values out with your code.

I specifically need to take the VendorTxCode & related value out of the string.

when I output decryptthis to the screen, I see it, but I need to take it out of the string so I can use it.

Comment: You should append this post to your question instead of posting it as an answer